# Video in email?

Tags: html, email, video

We often send emails in HTML for clients (Dont like it but not my choice)

Does anyone have any info or a link on support for the dynscrc attribute or img in email clients?

Answer (score 5):

My solution here would be to have a screenshot (perhaps with a 'click to watch' overlay) of your movie that links to a non-mail page that has a player in it.

Dealing with html email, in my experience, isn't so much about having standards as it is learning to compromise.  Web client and (the increasingly rare) desktop clients have differing behaviors that make website browser compliance seem like preschool by comparison.

Comment: I know what you mean and Im familiar with all that

- Im just trying to acertain the level of support (I know it can work in outlook 200-2003) and make a case to my client for or against

Answer (score 2):

Agreed that 'dynsrc' doesn't work, full stop.

You have three choices:

1. Put a still with a play button over the top - in my experience, this is pretty effective.
2. Use an animated GIF - you don't get any sound, and the quality is poor, but you can make it look video-ish. This doesn't work in Outlook 2007/10 either, because animated gifs don't work there.
3. Check your client-viewing base - if it's very high in Gmail, you could consider just using a YouTube tag as it will play in Gmail.

Answer (score 1):

Forget dynsrc. It doesn't work reliably in IE and it doesn't work in any other browser, and that's even before considering the varied limitations of mail clients and webmail services, and the difficulty of pushing something as large as a base64-encoded video file down the mail tube.

As ben said, link to a plain old web page including a Flash player.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that video in email support isn't universal and unfortunately – probably won't be for some time.  Email marketing service provider - Pinpointe http://www.pinpointe.com, tested video support in various email clients and the final verdict is that only Apple mail supports video in email reasonably well and Gmail supports a preview of youtube videos. There are a handful of possible ways to embed video with an email – here's a quick rundown of the possibilities:

- Flash.  Flash can be embedded in a web page by using an OBJECT tag
  with an EMBED tag placed inside, to embed a Javascript that will
  detect if Flash is installed. But… Email doesn't support Javascript. 
  Bummer – that means there's no way to detect if Flash is installed.
- Quicktime.  In web design, Quicktime is typically inserted in a
  web page the same way as Flash is – using the OBJECT and EMBED tags
  to embed a Javascript snippet.  Strike-out for Quicktime.
- Windows Media. Again – embedding Windows Media in a web page
  relies on using a OBJECT tag to embed the media file.  Struck out
  again.
- Embedded MPEG. Turns out that embedded MPEG will work on Outlook
- That's it.  And even so – you're sending an embedded video file.  Net result: Not practical.
- Animated GIF. Aahh. An animated GIF should look just like a GIF
  image, right?  Well Outlook 2007 explicitly does not support embedded
  animated GIFs (Outlook only displays the first frame of an animated
  GIF – thanks Microsoft…)  For other email clients that do support
  animated GIFs – there are still some tricky considerations.

  **In a nutshell:**

  - Animated GIF's don't include sound. Animated GIF emails are mostly
    not mobile friendly.
  - Animated GIFs are still subject to image blocking.  Since 70% of email clients now block images by default – the image is likely to be
    blocked altogether.
  - No user control – the animated GIF plays on opening

Answer (score 0):

I found some info here http://stylecampaign.com/blog/?p=29

not comprehensive.

Ben suggestion is something I would consider myself if appropriate to the situation